# Appears the same orders in the admin/commerce/orders and in the admin/commerce/orders/carts

Tags: commerce

In admin/commerce/orders appears the orders that order status is: Checkout:Payment,Checkout:Checkout,Shopping cart (these orders that appear in admin/commerce/orders/carts).Ι would like to appear only orders tha order status is:pending.
How could I do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I change filter creteria and the tab shopping cart disappeared,how could i appear the two tabs to admin(orders- shopping cart)

Comment: @nmanta84, you're encouraged to [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), if you found a solution post it as an answer and mark it as such. That way it will help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

In views list, there is one view named "Orders". In this view two pages are available:

1. "Orders"
2. "Shopping carts"

In "Shopping carts" page, click on `Commerce Order: Order state` from filter criteria and select states for which you want to display records.

Let me know if you face any future query with this.

Thanks!